# How to avoid the use of Spring annotations in my java beans and use them only in the configuration class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, annotations

I'm new in Spring and this is my first post here, I'm starting to use spring annotations, I was able to cofigure my project using XML configuration and now I'm able to configure it using only annotations and avoiding XML.

But my current need is to avoid the use of annotations in my java classes (beans) and use it only in my `AppConfig.java` class which I use to configure Spring.

This is my current working configuration:

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses= {BlocBuilder.class,... all my classes go here})
public class AppConfig {


  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype")
  public BlocBuilder blocBuilder(){ 
      return new BlocBuilder();
  }

}
```

And this is one of my java classes.

**BlocBuilder.java**

```
public class BlocBuilder {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("acServices")
private SomeInterface someInterface;

public SomeInterface getSomeInterface() {
    return someInterface;
}
public void setSomeInterface(SomeInterface someInterface) {
    this.someInterface = someInterface;
}
```

What I want to achieve is to avoid the use of annotations in my classes for example in my `BlocBuilder.java` class I don't want to have annotations and move them to my config class.

How can I manage it?

Any help whould be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructor injection is what you're looking for. Create a 1-arg constructor in `BlocBuilder` which takes `SomeInterface` type argument. And then in config class, pass it as argument:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses= {BlocBuilder.class,... all my classes go here})
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean
  public SomeInterface someInterface() {
      return new SomeInterfaceImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype")
  public BlocBuilder blocBuilder(){ 
      return new BlocBuilder(someInterface());
  }
}
```

Comment: that is basically my favorite approach too, but just to be complete. with this configuration it is also possible to have dependecies injected by setters. With regard to the original configuration, it would not be neccessary to create a single arg constructor, the BlocBuilder class may stay unchanged (after annotations have been removed =))

Comment: It's really what I needed, I tested your suggestion and it works fine, thank you very much.

Comment: That's amazing, this approach is simple and perfect.

Comment: Constructor injection has been part of Spring since before 1.0.  This is hardly amazing.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend a config class.  It'll couple all your beans together.

Spring configuration doesn't need to be an all or nothing thing: annotations or XML.  You can mix and match as you choose.  Put annotations in the classes you want and use XML for the rest.

Comment: My purpose is to avoid Xml configuration and use only  annotations, this is an imposition in our project. I have to find a way.

Comment: I use a top level xml file to define property placeholder (as I need environment runtime overrides) and component scan to my package where I keep all Java configuration classes. A little xml, but delegating to Java classes for bean creation with constructor injection (migrated away from large xml configuration and use of @Autowire).

Comment: The Spring bean factory is responsible for that.  I would dis courage you from coupling all your classes with a common config bean.

Comment: Why do you discourage it? Where do you see the difference between a config class and an XML file? Both couple your beans together, that's the point of a DI container.

Comment: I'm saying that the Spring bean factory already does what you need it to do.  You should not have to write another one.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to avoid XML, then you have to write the Spring configuration as Java config, hence you will have a config file where you define all the beans etc. (like in the answer from Rohit Jain).

Comment: Why are you going to such great lengths to avoid XML?  What is the harm?  Voting down; voting to close.

Comment: Why do you vote down and flag to close? It is a valid question, even if you don't like it. This isn't wikipedia.

Comment: @duffymo  In my case avoiding XML is an obligation , after all using XML or not, both are choices and I think there's nothing wrong about avoiding XML and having a Java Config class, otherwise why does it exist.