# How to configure SpringConfig.java file for JUnit testing

Tags: java, spring

I am using SpringConfig.java instead of SpringConfig.xml. In this class I return:

```
 @Bean(name = "restTemplate")
        public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
            return new RestTemplate();
        }
```

instead of writing

And I am using @Autowired and I am using SpringJunit4Classrunner. How can I configure SpringConfig.java and my JUnit test file to do proper dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use only annotations, you don't have to use `@Autowired` in other classes, all configurations have to be in SprinConfig.java. have a look in
[SpringConfig Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365919/how-to-avoid-the-use-of-spring-annotations-in-my-java-beans-and-use-them-only-in)

For Junit Configuration, you have to configure dependencies in `pom.xml` like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and your test class will be like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import package.SpringConfig;

public class SimpleTests {

@Test
public void Test() {

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
            SpringConfig.class);
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the following annotations above your class delcaration in your unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringConfig.class),
```

Comment: web.xml file also change to .java file, I need to configure that also..?

Comment: Still I am getting below issue  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration

Comment: Sounds as if SpringConfig is not implemented correctly - it should not contain an autowired field of type Configuration. Please add code.